# Node, Sequelize, Sync models, mixing force: true/false

Tags: mysql, node.js, model, sequelize.js

I'm confused (again).

While defining the database (MySQL) tables, using Sequelize, I want to do a 
sync(forced:true), to drop/create tables. So far so good.

Now I'm satisfied with my `user` table, and don't want to drop it on each run, while I continue to define other tables.

So, I would like to set a flag on `user` options, `sync: {forced: false}`

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  let Schema = sequelize.define(
    "user",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      BlaBla:{}
    },
    { // options
      sync: {force: false},
      freezeTableName: true,
      timestamps: true
    });
  return Schema;
};
```

This does not work. Table is dropped/created on each run.

Moving on to define my `company`table.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  let Schema = sequelize.define(
    "company",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      BlaBla:{}
    },
    { // options
      sync: {force: true},
      freezeTableName: true,
      timestamps: false
    });
  return Schema;
};
```

**Question**

- How do I selectively sync tables based on per `sequelize.define` options?

Comment: 1. I'm unable to find doc for using sync as an option in define.  Are you sure this is allowed?  2. If you sync() the tables individually ( rather than using sequelize.sync() for all tables), you can "force" differently on each table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a good nights sleep, my brain start to work again.

- First. I don't get why all examples of loading models, are creating an `db object`

  - to hold all models. `db[model.name] = model`
  - a reference to the Sequelize package `db.Sequelize = Sequelize`
  - a reference to the connection `db.sequelize = sequelize`

when the instance `const sequelize = new Sequelize()` is all you need.

- The connection object will hold a reference to all models imported.
  [public models: {}](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-member-models)

Given the `model definition` as in OP.
File: `app/models/user.js`

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  let Schema = sequelize.define(
    "user",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      BlaBla:{}
    },
    { // options
      sync: {force: false},
      freezeTableName: true,
      timestamps: true
    });
  return Schema;
};
```

And a bootstrap like this:
File: `config/sequelize.js`

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.dbname, config.dbuser, config.dbpass, {
    dialect: "mysql",
    host: config.dbhost,
    port:    3306,
    define: {
        engine: 'MYISAM',
        timestamps: true,
      }
  });

fs
  .readdirSync(path.join(config.models))
  .filter(file => ~file.indexOf('.js'))
  .forEach((file) => {
    let model = sequelize["import"](path.join(config.models, file));
    model.sync(model.options.sync);
  });

module.exports = sequelize;
```

**Then you have per model sync.**

Then in `server.js`:

```
const sequelize = require(join(__dirname,"config/sequelize"));
/* debug */
Object.keys(sequelize.models).forEach(function(name) {
    console.log('sequelize model:',name);
});

console.log('Checking DB connection...');
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Successfully connected to:', config.dbname);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    process.exit;
  });

const User = sequelize.model('user');
```

This results in `user` **NOT** being dropped, but `company`**IS** dropped.

Here is the console output from a run:

```
> node server.js

config/index.js { dbhost: '192.168.1.70',
  dbport: 3306,
  dbname: 'dbdev',
  dbuser: 'dbdev',
  dbpass: '********',
  mode: 'development',
  root: 'C:\\Workspace\\Github\\******',
  models: 'C:\\Workspace\\Github\\******\\app\\models',
  sync: false }

Creating DB connection...
Loading Schema: company
company sync { force: true }
Loading Schema: user
user sync { force: false }
sequelize model: company
sequelize model: user
Checking DB connection...
Server fetching: user
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `company`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `login` VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE, `password` VARCHAR(255), `fname` VARCHAR(45), `lname` VARCHAR(45), `email` VARCHAR(128), `phone` VARCHAR(20), `company` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdby` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `access` INTEGER, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=MYISAM;
Successfully connected to: dbdev
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `user`
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company` (`id` INTEGER auto_increment , `name` VARCHAR(255), `type` INTEGER, `createdby` INTEGER, `access` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=MYISAM;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `company`
```

I might take a look at `migrations`, but for now, I'd prefer to do initial modelling in the definition files as needed.

Did I miss some important point, or does this solution "fly" ?

Comment: Yes, that seems like a creative and sane way to drive sync'ing via the model definition.

Answer (score 3):

Sync'ing selectively in `sequelize.define()` is not supported. See the [Model Definition Configuration](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html#configuration) for details. Elsewhere in your project you must have a call to `sequelize.sync({force: true})` that is syncing all models. You should correct that first as it's bulk-forcing all your models to sync.

After fixing that, you have a few options going forward:

1: Use migrations going forward. Each addition or change to your schema is captured in a migration so you can roll each change out without resync'ing others.
See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/migrations.html

2: Sync each table separately as you're suggesting you'd like to. You'll need to call the `sync()` method for each model separately, for instance:

```
const user = require('./user');
const company = require('./company');
company.sync();
compant.sync({force:true});
```

This might be practical for early development, but as you progress in the project and begin releasing, migrations should be your method of choice to roll out schema changes.

See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html#database-synchronization